# How to setup basic auth globally in traefik v2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik, http-proxy

I'm using traefik 2.1 and would like to setup basic auth for all containers, in 1.x it was easy to do:

```
    [entryPoints.http.auth.basic]
    usersFile = "/etc/traefik/.htpasswd"
```

But how to setup it in 2.x? I'd like to avoid inserting code in all my docker-compose.yml files - got a lot of them.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is:

- we can use built-in middleware https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/basicauth/
- we need to connect middleware from above to a container which needs to be secured

Please find an example of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2.1"
  command:
    - "--api.insecure=true"
    - "--providers.docker=true"
    - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
    - "--providers.docker.network=default"
    - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    - "--api"
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  ports:
    - 80:80
    # management console
    - 8080:8080
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
    # auth middleware with user / password
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.my-auth.basicauth.users=test:$$apr1$$H6uskkkW$$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/,test2:$$apr1$$d9hr9HBB$$4HxwgUir3HP4EsggP/QNo0"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
      # connect your auth middleware to a service which you want to protect
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=my-auth"
```

So, now we can check that:

- auth has prompted on http://whoami.localhost
- the valid user name is "test:test" or "test2:test2"

You should use `htpasswd` command for generating a list of users and connect it according to the Traefik docs.

That's it. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to declare an attachment of a specific middleware to ALL routers / services instead of adding a specific middleware to each of those (image you don't have only the whoami service, but several others that need exactly the same middleware)?